# Where did James Bond pick up his rental car in Bahamas for Casino Royale?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

In Casino Royale, James Bond is seen in a car driving along in Nassau. When first arriving, he leaves from a helipad near Atlantis Resort, Paradise Island. While driving, he is seen driving along from the west side of Nassau.

[image: Atlantis Resort]

[image: GPS to Ocean Club]

Or did he get this car from an associate?

Comment: Well, couldn't he just have gone to a car rental office and rent one? No need to show this to the audience. Or is there actually more to this question (you might give more details if I missed the point of the question, but at the moment I can't see none).

Comment: The Ocean Club is already on Paradise Island meaning that it would take him a 2 minute taxi ride from his current location to the Ocean Club. There are extra scenes I did not add that show Bond driving along the South of Nassau (off Paradise Island). Meaning that he would have had to pick his car up near Nassau Airport as most popular rental agencies are near there.

Comment: Then the boat plane scene (above) wouldn't make sense seeing that he could have just taken a flight to Nassau Airport and taken the car from there. It could come down to inconsistency and not enough filming locations to ensure proper viewing of Nassau but I wanted to be sure

Comment: Ok, with your comments the question makes much more sense to me. Maybe you could add this information to the question, as I'm sure there are more people like me that aren't acquainted that well with the geography of the Bahamas.

Comment: I'm going to close this because, as this question currently stands, it seems more of a plot-hole question and is off-topic.  If you find more details for your question, or figure out the answer, please edit and flag for reopening.

Comment: @DForck42 - Questions about plotting are on-topic. If you think it's a plot hole *and can back that up with some proof*, then put that in an answer...

Answer (score 4):

Most movies do not try to maintain a consistent geography of real life places.  To say there are countless examples of stuff like this would be an understatement - I would guess over 90% of films have scenes where characters go down the street, turn a corner, and wind up in an entirely different part of the city.

The intent is always to serve the needs of the story and the visuals.

The hope is the scenery is non-descript enough that even locals don't notice.  I don't think you should look for a plot-based explanation for this.

Comment: Just like almost every movie or TV show uses the Golden Gate Bridge visual in a San Francisco based story. The bridge is not on the primary way to most things there.